# how to get device Id for FCM registration in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

i am trying to connect xamarin app with Azure notification hub. 
for registration i am using this code in onTokenRefresh method.

```
     var client = new MobileServiceClient(App.MobileServiceUrl);
                var push = client.GetPush();
                var reg = new Registration("??????????", new List<string> { "someTag" });
                await push.RegisterAsync(reg);
```

Registration object needs "deviceId" as first parameter.
where to get this id from, in xamarin's Android project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain that id via the static Firebase instance token property

```
FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token
```

So this should work:

```
var reg = new Registration(FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token, new List<string> { "someTag" });
```